# PHP send a parameter from href to another page privately

Tags: php, get, href

I have created a page with PHP that contains `href` links :

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com?link=myvalue1">
<a href="http://www.mypage.com?link=myvalue2">
```

...

I use `$_GET['link']` in the destination page to get `myvalue1`...

The problem is that myvalue1 is visible in the URL (and also in the `href` link page source) although this parameter is confidential.

Could someone know a way to secure this process ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use GET if you want the data to be secure. You need to use POST for this (and use https instead of http to be completely secure). Since `<a>` links can only use GET, you'll have to use forms to create the POST, for example:

```
<form action="http://www.mypage.com" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value="myvalue1" />
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">myvalue1</a>
</form>
<form action="http://www.mypage.com" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value="myvalue2" />
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">myvalue2</a>
</form>
```

(Note that this is a really inelegant way to do this, but you get the point.)

Then in PHP use `$_POST['link']` instead of `$_GET['link']`.

Comment: thanks a lot ! is the value visible is sill visible if  the visitor make "show source code" ?

Comment: also in my destination page i use an IFRAME src="....myvalue1" and i am afraid this will be visible in the source code

Comment: Yes, the value will be visible in both places in the source code, the only way to hide it is to handle the value server-side and refer to it with an ID or something. It's hard to be specific without knowing more about the use case.

Comment: thanks, sorry i really can't how it could be used server side...Actually, myvalueXX is the name of files uploaded on there server. But i don't want people can see path of these files and give the URL to someone else...

Comment: That is a whole other question: "How can I prevent my users from sharing their URL?" and it has no simple answer. But for this case, maybe you could have a table that contains the paths and refer to those with row IDs, and have some sort of user access control to check if the user has the permissions to access that file?